# Cache Control C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a menu on a .net page that periodically returns a 404 when clicking the link the first time you visit the page.  I'm trying to set the caching to 0 on the page to eliminate server caching as a possibility for the error.  Is there a way to set it in the HTML?  I'm looking for Response.Expires = -1 as a page directive or something along those lines?

Comment: Is it webforms or mvc or web api or something else?

Comment: The Browser cache can usually be turned off in the F12 developer tools.

Comment: @IainBallard I think he wants to change that server-side instead of asking every single visitor to do so.

Comment: It's actually MVC as part of a CMS

Comment: have you tried in the web.config (provided that is an option)? <httpProtocol><customHeaders><add name="Expires" value="-1" /></customHeaders></httpProtocol>? Personally, I also have one for Pragma and Cache-Control as well (no-cache for both)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a filter like this

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class NoCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

And while defining a controller you can annotation:

```
[NoCache]
public class ControllerBase : Controller, IControllerBase
```

Also you can define in particular controller action:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Action methods inside your Controllers:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*", Location = OutputCacheLocation.None)]
```